# How to create Android native Tab bar in android using phoneGap?

Tags: android, cordova, tabs

I am using PhoneGap 3.4.0 to build a hybrid application for iOS and Android, and i want to use the native Tab bar of both in my application. In Android build I am not able to produce the Tab bar in index.html file, however I can set tab bar in java class.

Comment: You will need to create a custom project or create a cordova plugin for this.

Comment: @DawsonLoudon : Any link for reference ?

Comment: Instead of going native I would use http://topcoat.io and do it with html, but if you need to go native check out the phonegap docs for creating a cordova plugin. beyond that you would need to know how to make an android project from scratch and include the phonegap view as a sub view. I am not aware any tuts for this as it's fairly advanced.

Answer (score 0):

See the following web resources to get idea how to work with plugins:

http://andidog.de/blog/2012/10/new-tab-bar-phonegap-plugin-for-android-based-on-actionbarsherlock/

https://github.com/AndiDog/phonegap-android-actionbarsherlock-tabbar-plugin